# how to configure any restful api package like laravel/passort or dingo/api in laravel version 5.0.35 (*without composer)

Tags: php, laravel-5, restful-authentication

I am trying to create rest api's in laravel(version 5.0.35).
Official documentation is not provided for 5.0
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/api-authentication

Tried Laravel passport but I assume it works for version 5.3>
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/passport

Tried dingo/api https://github.com/dingo/api/
But its dependencies caused a fatal breakdown.

*P.S: composer is broke down, I had to install the mentioned packages manually

Laravel Version: **5.0.35**
PHP version: **7.0.27**
config/app.php-> Providers array as following:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
    'Devitek\Core\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
    'Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider',
    'Iamnotstatic\LaravelAPIAuth\LaravelAPIAuthServiceProvider',
    
    //'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider',

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider', 
    //'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider', 

    'App\Providers\SettingsServiceProvider',
    'App\Providers\DropboxFilesystemServiceProvider',

    'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
    'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',
    'Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider',
],
```

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your Laravel version to a more recent one?

Comment: Not so sure about the consequences of framework update as it is a pre-built system, so update could possibly cause more issues.

Comment: I'd make a copy of the project and try to upgrade the copy as to not "damage" your original project. In the long run you'll have a hard time finding any decent package for this outdated Laravel version. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Have you looked into using JWT for you api? Something like tymon works well for api.